# Не передается имя файла методом POST

Tags: php

Нужно получить имя файла и передать его обработчику на php.
Пытаюсь делать так:

```
<form id="ff" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="addbufs.php">
    <p><input type="file" name="fn" form="ff"></p>
    <p><input id="but" type="submit" value="Загрузить"></p>
</form>
```

при этом в обработчике addbufs.php в `$var = $_POST["fn"];` пусто, наличие/отсутствие `id="ff"` на результат не влияет. При использовании метода `GET` работает нормально. Использование метода `POST` в других случаях никаких проблем не вызывает. Использую Денвер.

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4):

Вместо $_POST используйте $_FILES

Comment: при использовании  $_FILES вместо имени файла получаю Array

Comment: сделайте print_r($_FILES) и все сразу станет понятно

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю вам стоит попробовать так:

```
echo $_FILES['fn']['name'];
```